# Send mail from a different address or alias on Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-apps-email, user-accounts

I'm trying to add an alias to my Google Apps for Business Gmail account following this article:

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en&ref_topic=3395757

But at the step 5 "Click Next Step >> and then click Send Verification. Gmail will send a verification message to your other email address to confirm that you own it." I'm always getting the following error, no matter what account I try to configure.

[image: Error screen]

Is it a new feature of Google Apps for Business? A Bug? What can I do about it?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this isn't an option anymore:

> We rolled out a change for new accounts where if you would like to send mail as from a non-Gmail or non-Google Apps account, you can no longer use the option of Gmail's servers to send your mail.
>
> Any accounts which previously were using Send Mail As via Gmail servers will not be affected, you can keep the previous set up.

Quoted from [Google Operating System blog](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2014/08/external-addresses-no-longer-use-gmail.html)

Comment: This would be a better answer if you included the salient information from that link.